# Trouble reading strings and int in a row with scanf

Tags: c, string, struct, int, scanf

I have to read 3 strings seperated by spaces and 2 integers separated by spaces as well and save them to a struct

```
  #define n 5;
    struct person
    {
        char last_name[20];
        char sec_last_name[20];
        char name[20];
        int num;
        int kw;
    }client[n];
```

I tried reading it like this

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{    
    scanf("%s %s %s %d %d",client[i].last_name,client[i].sec_last_name,client[i].name,client[i].num,client[i].kw);
}
```

Since I have to read it in a row, but when I run the program it stops after typing in the first row of data and hitting enter, after playing around with my code the problem has to do with reading the integers but i cant seem to solve it.

Comment: change to `&client[i].num, &client[i].kw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanf statement is having syntax error. `&` should be used before integer in your case.

```
 scanf("%s %s %s %d %d",client[i].last_name,client[i].sec_last_name,client[i].name,&client[i].num,&client[i].kw);
```

One more thing is,

```
#define n 5 /*;*/
```

`;` should not be used.

**Example:**

If `;` is used, then it will be replace client[5;]; in structure variable declaration. Then it will issue an compilation error.